# Selenium doesn't work in docker: cannot create temp dir for user data dir

Tags: python, docker, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

For some reason selenium can't run fully in docker.
Reproducing error: some unit tests need the current page. The get_soup.py file, which is run during the unit test, is responsible for retrieving and saving the current page to Fixtures. It should fetch the current page and save it to the file for the test to work.
The problem occurs when I try to call the tests through while the container is running:  "docker exec -it my_container sh -c "python3 -m pytest source"".
It ends with the message: "E selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: cannot create temp dir for user data dir".

get_soup.py:

```python
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time


def get_current_soup():
    options = Options()
    options.add_argument("--headless")
    options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
    driver.set_window_size(1400,1000)
    driver.get("https://www.pepper.pl/nowe")
    time.sleep(0.7)
    page = driver.page_source
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page, "html5lib")

    with open("pepper_app/tests/fixtures/to_test_article_and_soup/soup_to_check.html", 'w', encoding='utf-8') as file:
        file.write(str(soup))

    driver.quit()
```

Below is my dockerfile:

```dockerfile
FROM python:3.9
LABEL maintainer="dbyl.developer"

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1 \
    APP_DIR=/app

COPY ./requirements.txt /tmp/requirements.txt
COPY ./requirements.dev.txt /tmp/requirements.dev.txt
COPY ./source /source
WORKDIR ${APP_DIR}
EXPOSE 8000


ARG CHROME_VERSION="google-chrome-stable"
RUN wget -q -O - https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | apt-key add - \
  && echo "deb http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list \
  && apt-get update -qqy \
  && apt-get -qqy install \
    ${CHROME_VERSION:-google-chrome-stable} \
  && rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list \
  && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /var/cache/apt/*


# Chrome webdriver
#============================================
# can specify versions by CHROME_DRIVER_VERSION
# Latest released version will be used by default
#============================================
ARG CHROME_DRIVER_VERSION
RUN if [ ! -z "$CHROME_DRIVER_VERSION" ]; \
  then CHROME_DRIVER_URL=https://edgedl.me.gvt1.com/edgedl/chrome/chrome-for-testing/$CHROME_DRIVER_VERSION/linux64/chromedriver-linux64.zip ; \
  else echo "Geting ChromeDriver latest version from https://googlechromelabs.github.io/chrome-for-testing/LATEST_RELEASE_" \
    && CHROME_MAJOR_VERSION=$(google-chrome --version | sed -E "s/.* ([0-9]+)(\.[0-9]+){3}.*/\1/") \
    && CHROME_DRIVER_VERSION=$(wget -qO- https://googlechromelabs.github.io/chrome-for-testing/LATEST_RELEASE_${CHROME_MAJOR_VERSION} | sed 's/\r$//') \
    && CHROME_DRIVER_URL=https://edgedl.me.gvt1.com/edgedl/chrome/chrome-for-testing/$CHROME_DRIVER_VERSION/linux64/chromedriver-linux64.zip ; \
  fi \
  && echo "Using ChromeDriver from: "$CHROME_DRIVER_URL \
  && echo "Using ChromeDriver version: "$CHROME_DRIVER_VERSION \
  && wget --no-verbose -O /tmp/chromedriver_linux64.zip $CHROME_DRIVER_URL \
  && rm -rf /opt/selenium/chromedriver \
  && unzip /tmp/chromedriver_linux64.zip -d /opt/selenium \
  && rm /tmp/chromedriver_linux64.zip \
  && mv /opt/selenium/chromedriver-linux64/chromedriver /opt/selenium/chromedriver-$CHROME_DRIVER_VERSION \
  && chmod 777 /opt/selenium/chromedriver-$CHROME_DRIVER_VERSION \
  && ln -fs /opt/selenium/chromedriver-$CHROME_DRIVER_VERSION /usr/bin/chromedriver

ARG DEV=false
RUN python -m venv /py && \
    /py/bin/pip install --upgrade pip && \
    /py/bin/pip3 install -r /tmp/requirements.txt && \
    if [ $DEV = "true" ]; \
        then /py/bin/pip install -r /tmp/requirements.dev.txt ; \
    fi && \
    rm -rf /tmp && \
    adduser \
        --disabled-password \
        --no-create-home \
        django-user

ENV PATH="/py/bin:$PATH"
```

At the moment I tried different versions of chromedriver. I also tried running webdriver with different options. However, there is probably a bug related to docker permissions that I can't fix.